# column not null deferrable

Tags: oracle, data-integrity

In Oracle deferred constraints are checked only at the point of commit.

What is the meaning of DEFERRABLE clause in a case of NOT NULL constraint?
For example

```
create table test(a number not null deferrable, b number);
insert into test(a,b) values (222, 111);
commit;
```

After these statements I thought the following code would work

```
update test set a = null where b = 111;
delete test where b = 111;
commit;
```

But it doesn't.

What is the difference between two definitions?

```
create table test1(a number not null deferrable, b number);
create table test2(a number not null, b number);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two options here. Either you need to set the constraint to be deferred within the transaction by using the command shown below

```
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;
```

This should be run before doing the `UPDATE` statement that you have defined.

Alternatively you can set the constraint to be `INITIALLY DEFERRED` in the table definition

```
create table test(a number not null initially deferred deferrable, b number);
```

After doing either of these things, you should then be able to run the DML that you have in the question.

Comment: Yes, you are right. With INITIALLY DEFERRED my code works. Thanks.